# Magento 2.3.0 product image cache resizing images to look very bad

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento2.3, image-resizing

i have uploaded images to **magento 2.3** and when i look on product page i can see it been resizing to different size with white lines.
look at original image that has been uploaded: https://babybeddingdesign.r.worldssl.net/pub/media/catalog/product/d/u/dumbo_bedding_set.jpg

the one seen on my site: https://babybeddingdesign.r.worldssl.net/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/9d08971813a040f8f96067a40f75c615/d/u/dumbo_bedding_set.jpg

link to the item: https://babybeddingdesign.com/dumbo-crib-bedding-collection-crib-bedding-set

all my products also old ones have been resizing. what is the problem with Magento 2.3?

Answer (score 1):

In `etc/view.xml` of your current theme, you can update product image size

Make sure you resize with the expect ratio.

Use additional tag `<frame>` to prevent white borders on image. Use this code as example:

```
<image id="product_page_main_image" type="small_image">
    <width>460</width>
    <height>460</height>
    <aspect_ratio>true</aspect_ratio>
    <frame>false</frame>
</image>
```

Check all other tags, not just a tag with the id `product_page_main_image` check others too.

`<frame>false</frame>` was an issue in previous versions, it was not working in old 2.x versions and [reported earlier](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4622)

**Note: If you still getting white border issue, then you need to use the below fix until it's offically released:**

> After creating a plugin to convert the string value to an integer
>   (which properly casts to a boolean), the image frame is not added. For [details see this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4622)

```
public function beforeSetKeepFrame($image, $keep)
{
    if (is_string($keep)) {
        $keep = (strtolower($keep) === 'true') ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return [$keep];
}
```

Comment: nothing have help me i just copy from media to cache folder.

but this is a temporary solution, what will be next time when I clean cache?